# Latex gives me an error when I add list items to the file

Tags: latex, pdflatex, overleaf

I'm very new to latex and can't figure out why it's giving me a error here. The file breaks as soon as I add the list items I can't figure out why. Thanks in advance

```
      \resumeProjectHeading
          {\textbf{Thud Bull 3D} $|$ \url{https://youtube.com/shorts/_uPbmqhA41Q?}}
      \resumeItemListStart
      \resumeItem{Developed a hyper-casual mobile game using C\# and Unity, achieving a CPI of \$1.85 and a play rate of 2m25sec}
      \resumeItemListEnd
           
    \resumeSubHeadingListEnd
```

- Works when it's like this
  `\resumeProjectHeading {\textbf{Thud Bull 3D} $|$ \url{https://youtube.com/shorts/_uPbmqhA41Q?}}`
  but breaks when I add the the list stuff

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is issue with your indentation, but worth a try fixing it.

```
\resumeProjectHeading
    {\textbf{Thud Bull 3D} $|$ \url{https://youtube.com/shorts/_uPbmqhA41Q?}}
\resumeItemListStart
    \resumeItem{Developed a hyper-casual mobile game using C\# and Unity, achieving a CPI of \$1.85 and a play rate of 2m25sec}
\resumeItemListEnd
\resumeSubHeadingListEnd
```